# Enable credit card/guest payment for PayPal Invoice

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've created an invoice using PayPal [Invoicing REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/v2/#invoices_create). Invoice is created properly and later sent but there is no option to pay without PayPal account. When customer clicks on link in email or invoice link in my application, login pop-up is shown and there is no option to pay with credit card - [something like this](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/PayPal-Payments-Standard/Guest-checkout-disappeared-Customers-FORCED-to-create-paypal/td-p/2368385) (2nd image on page)

[image: No credit card option]

In my app settings on PayPal  "Advanced Credit and Debit Card Payments" is enabled and "PayPal account optional" is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guest availability in the paypal.com checkout depends on very many factors, including the IP address and geographic location of the buyer, the amount of the transaction, the device used, and any number of other things. Other than *disabling* "PayPal Account Optional" as a possibility in your account, you cannot control this behavior of the PayPal checkout page.

---

"Advanced Credit and Debit Card Payments" , or a more simple standard "Debit or Credit Card" button integration [using the JS SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) give you control over the behavior on your *own* site (not in the paypal.com checkout itself). So you could conceivably create your own invoice page and link to that page, if you want to do that work rather than use what's ready-made by PayPal's invoice system.